# How to get two values from json object through lodash?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I am new in json and lodash. I want to get two values from Json. But right now i am getting only one value from return. So I want to get together  both values.

```
[
{
"_id": {   
"mm": 2,   
"hr": 9,
"sl": 1
},
"tot": 188
},
{
"_id": {   
"mm": 2,   
"hr": 4,
"sl": 3
},
"tot": 622
},
{
"_id": {   
"mm": 2,   
"hr": 12,
"sl": 5
},
"tot": 484


 }]
```

---

```
_.map(resp.data,function(res){ return res._id.hr})
```

I want to also get sl value with "hr" Like 9:1, 4:3, 12:5. (hr:sl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an object with all the data you want, for example:

```
var results =_.map(a, function(res) { 
  return { hr: res._id.hr, sl: res._id.sl }; 
});
```

[Example on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tuqucuz/edit?js,console)

Comment: I want to add 1 with res._id.sl. can it possible

Comment: You mean add 1 to the value of sl? If so you'd return an object like: { hr: res._id.hr, sl: res._id.sl + 1 }

Comment: I have done this things but showing like 12:31 but i want 12:40. can you show in jsbin

Comment: I've updated the JSBin to show examples of returning the values as a combined string like in your question and also incrementing one of the values. You need to be careful with brackets here as js will concatenate the '1' instead of adding it as it treats the result as a string, not a number.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. can it possible when comes 12.6 or 13.6 or 14.6 then it will round like 13 or 14 or 15

Comment: Of course. I see now from some of the other comments that these are times (hours and minutes). You can round the values using Math.round and Math.floor (I've added examples at the bottom the the JSBin.)

Comment: ...but note that to round numbers they'll need to be in the format (12.1 as opposed to 12:1). Also, if you're dealing with time values and want to manipulate them you may want to consider the moment.js library?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help:

```
var json = [
   {
      "_id":{
         "mm":2,
         "hr":9,
         "sl":1
      },
      "tot":188
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "mm":2,
         "hr":4,
         "sl":3
      },
      "tot":622
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "mm":2,
         "hr":12,
         "sl":5
      },
      "tot":484
   }
]

$data = _.map(json,function(res){ return (res._id.hr + ':' + res._id.sl)})
console.log($data);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dedenbangkit/qcqbsb69/

Ok, if you want to put another ten minutes for the _.id.sl variables, you can do this:

```
$data = _.map(json,function(res){
$hour = res._id.hr;
$minute = (res._id.sl*10) + 10;
if ($minute >= 60)
{
    $minute = '00';
  $hour = $hour +1;
}
return ($hour + ':' + $minute)
})
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dedenbangkit/qcqbsb69/1/

Sorry, I think you don't want 24 become 25 for hour format isn't it?
so this will might better for you, assuming that 00:00 is middle night.

```
$data = _.map(json,function(res){
$hour = res._id.hr;
$minute = (res._id.sl*10) + 10;
    if ($minute > 50){
      $minute = '0' + (60 - $minute);
      $hour = $hour + 1;
    }else{
      $hour = $hour + 1;
    }

    if($hour > 24){
      $hour = '0' + (- 24 + $hour);
    }

    return ($hour + ':' + $minute)
})
```

Another update: https://jsfiddle.net/dedenbangkit/qcqbsb69/4/

Comment: Can we add 1 to "sl" then its become 9.10 to 9:20, 4:30 to 4:40, 12:50 to 13:00

Comment: Actually this is hr:minute  and I want to show 9:10--9:20. Add 10 minutes. "sl" means minute

Comment: Something like this? $data = _.map(json,function(res){
$hour = res._id.hr;
$minute = (res._id.sl*10) + 10;
if ($minute >= 60)
{
 $minute = '00';
  $hour = $hour +1;
}
return ($hour + ':' + $minute)
})

Answer (score 0):

**Using Vanilla JS**

```js
var arr = [
{
"_id": {   
"mm": 2,   
"hr": 9,
"sl": 1
},
"tot": 188
},
{
"_id": {   
"mm": 2,   
"hr": 4,
"sl": 3
},
"tot": 622
},
{
"_id": {   
"mm": 2,   
"hr": 12,
"sl": 5
},
"tot": 484
 }]
 
 var res = arr.map((item) => item._id.hr + " : " + item._id.sl )
 console.log(res)
```

**Using loaddash**

```js
var arr = [{
  "_id": {   
  "mm": 2,   
  "hr": 9,
  "sl": 1
  },
  "tot": 188
  },
  {
  "_id": {   
  "mm": 2,   
  "hr": 4,
  "sl": 3
  },
  "tot": 622
  },
  {
  "_id": {   
  "mm": 2,   
  "hr": 12,
  "sl": 5
  },
  "tot": 484
  }]
 
var res = _.map(arr, (item) => item._id.hr + " : " + item._id.sl )
 console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```